# Visual Studio PerfTips elapsed time is different to the time from StopWatch

Tags: visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 2017 to debug my code and leverage PerfTips to get the rough elapsed time of a function call.

But I just found big difference between perftips time and the time from StopWatch().

Example:

```
var sw=StopWatch();
sw.Start();
MyFunction();
sw.Stop();
```

I set break point before and after the MyFunction() call, PerfTips shows the elapsed time of MyFunction() call is around 260 ms.

But the sw.Elapsed.TotalMillionSeconds value is > 1000 ms. Why so big difference?
Anything wrong of my StopWatch usage or perftips?

BTW: I check the stopwatch time value in debugger mode, that is, set break point on sw.Stop, and read the value on debugger window. Is it incorrect way to get the accurate StopWatch() value?

Comment: You may be experiencing the [Microsoft Minute](http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/99mar/19990318.html).

Comment: This is an old question and you probably moved on - but the problem seems to be that you had your breakpoint on sw.Stop(); which causes the debugger to break BEFORE executing the line which is stopping the stopwatch. So by the time you looked up the value of the stopwatch in the IDE, more time had passed.